# How to upload a qmake-based package to my PPA?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I have an application that uses qmake that I'd like to upload to my PPA.

How can I set up the package so that the project builds properly?

Comment: There is no direct relation between building and PPAs, you mean you want to know how to create package building rules for a source which builds using qmake ?

Comment: @João: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching: (okay, a **lot** of searching)

[This](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/PackagingGuide/QtApplication) page seems to contain some information on setting up a Debian package that uses qmake.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial linked to is a bit old, but will still work. Though things should be much simpler now. debhelper's simplified rules files have supported qmake since version 7.4.12. Depending on any additional requirements of your package, a minimal rules file could be a small as:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@
```